# Improve performance without using NOT IN

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance, sqlperformance

I want to exclude a row containing the value 'pre_d_eng_tb' from action_name attribute in the output, using NOT IN makes the query slower (~45sec), are there any other possibilities to improve performance, without using this filter query takes less than (~4sec)

```
    select
    date(action_event_time),
    syndicator_id,
    ac.action_name as 'conversion_type',
    count (distinct ac.syndicator_id || '|' ||
                    ac.campaign_id || '|' ||
                    ac.target_item_id || '|' ||
                    ac.source_item_id || '|' ||
                    ac.affiliate_id || '|' ||
                    ac.country|| '|' ||
                    ifnull(ac.platform_id,5) || '|' ||
                    ac.user_id || '|' ||
                    ac.ip_address || '|' ||
                    ifnull(SUBSTRING(ac.action_goal_page_url, 1, 500),'--') || '|' ||
                    ifnull(ac.action_name,'--') || '|' ||
                    ifnull(ac.action_revenue,0) || '|' ||
                    ifnull(ac.action_order_id,'--') || '|' ||
                    ifnull(ac.action_currency,'--') || '|' ||
                    CASE
                        WHEN ac.action_name in ('video_page_view', 'text_page_view', 'photo_page_view', 'homepage_page_view', 'article_page_view','category_page_view', 'page_view', 'home_page_view', 'video_view','pages_per_visit')
                            then ifnull(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ac.action_event_time),0)

                        ELSE ifnull(FLOOR(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ac.action_event_time)/ 900),0) end) as 'conversions'
from rawdata.action_conversion_v2 ac join trc.publishers sy on sy.id = ac.syndicator_id
where ac.action_name not in ('pre_d_eng_tb')
  and NEW_TIME(ac.click_event_time,'GMT',sy.time_zone_name) >= date('2020-05-01')
  and NEW_TIME(ac.click_event_time,'GMT',sy.time_zone_name) < date('2020-06-15') + interval '1' day
  and syndicator_id = 1223211
group by 1,2,3
order by 1 asc;
```

The query is working fine its gives result in below format its just its taking longer time which i want to improve

```
 date   syndicator_id   conversion_type conversions
    2020-04-30  1223211 page_view             2
    2020-05-01  1223211 make_purchase         45
    2020-05-01  1223211 page_view             3645
    2020-05-02  1223211 make_purchase         36
    2020-05-02  1223211 page_view             4936
    2020-05-03  1223211 make_purchase         39
```

[image: Schema]

Comment: why use "not in" for a single string? Surely "not =" is more appropriate. Do you have an index for this column?

Comment: Can you also provide the execution plan with and without the filter? Read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056) for tips on asking a good SQL question.

Comment: What's the table schema? Indexes?

Comment: @gbjbaanb: my understanding is that `not in` is just syntactic sugar anyway and results in the system just doing a series of `and <>` anyway.

Comment: @gbjbaanb It's likely that MySQL will recognize that `NOT IN (singleton)` is equivalent to `!= singleton` and generate the same code.

Comment: The general problem is that non-equality can't make as effective use of indexes as equality. There's nothing specific to search for in the index.

Comment: Is there really a table named `_v2` or is that a view?

Comment: This is a table not a view, i have initially tried with != and <> but the results were taking 5s longer, and when i tried with not in it took a little less time, attached the schema in the question for better understanding

Comment: Since `!=` is not well optimized, I suspect this discussion of `NOT IN` is moot.

Comment: @Khushal - Please provide the `EXPLAIN SELECT` for the forms that were slower and faster.  I would like to see what changes in the execution plan.

Comment: Consider testing `COUNT(DISTINCT a,b,c)` in place of `COUNT(DISTINCT a || '|' || b || '|' || c)`.  Also, the `IFNULL()s` may not be necessary.

Comment: Is `NEW_TIME` a Stored Function?  What indexes exist on the tables?

Comment: How big is the table (GB)?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: @Barmar I'd expect that too, but only if the optimiser gets involved. Usually "not in" creates a kind of mini-table and performs a form of join against it. But its still probably indexes at fault, its always indexes :)

Answer (score 0):

It may not be possible to speed up the query much, *as it stands*.  However, by building and maintaining a "summary table", you might make the query run several times as fast.

Every night, summarize the day's traffic and add subtotals to a summary table.  It would be indexed by a date, (from `date(action_event_time)`, syndicator_id, and 'conversion_type'.

The 'report' would sum up the subtotals.

However, there is a monkey wrench -- the `COUNT(DISTINCT...)`.  It is very hard to do "subtotaling" for such.  You really wanted to find out the number of different values, excluding pre_d_eng_tb?

I assume there is an index starting with `syndicator_id`?

Another thought...

```
NEW_TIME(ac.click_event_time,'GMT',sy.time_zone_name)
```

inhibits a critical thing for optimization -- filtering on the `WHERE` clause.  Consider doing that conversion *before* storing the click time into `ac`.  That way, you could have `INDEX(syndicator_id, click_time)`, which should speed up the filtering.  (`action_name` is still a big nuisance.)

If desired, add a second column for click_time -- one being the raw time; the other being the "new_time".